# How to build a rolling window procedure using racket/scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

When written this way the error says: 4 parts after if:

```
(define (rolling-window l size)
  (if (< (length l) size) l
  (take l size) (rolling-window (cdr l) size)))
```

and when there's another paranthesis to make it 3 parts:

```
(define (rolling-window l size)
  (if (< (length l) size) l
  ((take l size) (rolling-window (cdr l) size))))
```

then it says: application: not a procedure;

Comment: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html

Comment: Use `cond`. Alternatively, wrap the branch with `begin` or `let`, but using `cond` is probably easier.

Comment: (take l size) (rolling-window (cdr l) size)
should be both in the else part no need for a third alternative

Comment: @X10D the else part can only be one expression so it's `(take l size)` and `(rollwing-window (cdr l) size)` cannot be in the `if` form since it's a fourth part, eg. after the else part. If you were to wrap it in `begin` then `(take l size)` would return a result *that is never used*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to write more than one expression in if's else in racket/scheme?

Well that's not really the question. The question is **"How to build a *rolling window* procedure using racket?"**. Anyway, it looks like you're probably coming from another programming language. Processing linked lists can be a little tricky at first. But remember, to compute the length of a list, you have to iterate through the entire list. So using `length` is a bit of an anti-pattern here.

Instead, I would recommend you create an `aux`iliary procedure inside your `rolling-window` procedure which builds up the window as you iterate thru the list. This way you don't have to waste iterations counting elements of a list.

Then if your `aux` procedure ever returns and empty window, you know you're done computing the windows for the given input list.

```
(define (rolling-window n xs)
  (define (aux n xs)
    (let aux-loop ([n n] [xs xs] [k identity])
      (cond [(= n 0) (k empty)] ;; done building sublist, return sublist
            [(empty? xs) empty] ;; reached end of xs before n = 0, return empty window
            [else (aux-loop (sub1 n) (cdr xs) (λ (rest) (k (cons (car xs) rest))))]))) ;; continue building sublist

  (let loop ([xs xs] [window (aux n xs)] [k identity])
    (cond ([empty? window] (k empty)) ;; empty window, done
          ([empty? xs] (k empty))     ;; empty input list, done
          (else (loop (cdr xs) (aux n (cdr xs)) (λ (rest) (k (cons window rest)))))))) ;; continue building sublists

(rolling-window 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
;; => '((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6))
```

It works for empty windows

```
(rolling-window 0 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
;; => '()
```

And empty lists too

```
(rolling-window 3 '())
;; => '()
```

Comment: A very nice solution. One tiny remark: Since loop doesn't modify `n` it can be left out of the argument list.

Comment: what's the etymology of xs?

Comment: @X10D , `xs` is just plural of `x`. It's a collection of multiple `x` values — maybe in a List, an Array, a Tuple, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative:

```
#lang racket

(define (rolling-window n xs)
  (define v (list->vector xs))
  (define m (vector-length v))
  (for/list ([i (max 0 (- m n -1))])
    (vector->list (vector-copy v i (+ i n)))))

(rolling-window 3 '(a b c d e f g))
(rolling-window 3 '())
(rolling-window 0 '(a b c))
```

Output:

```
'((a b c) (b c d) (c d e) (d e f) (e f g))
'()
'(() () () ())   ; lack of spec makes this ok !
```

Answer (score 1):

Following modification of OP's function works. It includes an outlist for which the initial default is empty list. Sublists are added to this outlist till `(length l)` is less than `size`.

```
(define (rolling-window l size (ol '()))
  (if (< (length l) size)  (reverse ol)
      (rolling-window (cdr l) size (cons (take l size) ol))))
```

Testing:

```
(rolling-window '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 2)
(rolling-window '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 3)
(rolling-window '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 4)
```

Output:

```
'((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 6))
'((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6))
'((1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Any improvements on this one?

```
(define (rolling-window l size)
  (cond ((eq? l '()) '())
        ((< (length l) size) '())
        ((cons (take l size) (rolling-window (cdr l) size)))))
```

Comment: 1: It would be nice to get rid of the length checking. any way to compose the take function with something so that it exits silently when the list isn't long enough instead of throwing a list too short error?
2: yes it's less efficient but a bit more readable?